# Are there any rules regarding special characters/entities and innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, cross-browser

When I use innerHTML from javascript, the browser (Safari and Firefox at least) seem to replace certain characters and numeric entities with their named entities.

The character `\xa0` (non breaking space) gets replaced by `&nbsp;`, 
 `&#60;` (lesser than) gets replaced by `&lt;`. But for example the umlaut ü is not replaced with `&uuml;`.

I have not found any documentation for this behaviour.

A simple demo:

```
<h2 id="withoutnbsp">This does not use en be es pe (uses the \xa0 character)</h2>
<script>alert(document.getElementById("withoutnbsp").innerHTML);</script>
```

A more elaborate demonstration can be found here:

http://gist.github.com/89434

You can use the "raw" link on the gist page, to view it in your browser.

I need to know exactly which characters innerHTML replaces. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML 5 spec has rules for serializing an HTML fragment when you call innerHTML on it, documented here: [Serializing HTML fragments](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090212/serializing-html-fragments.html) (note that innerHTML isn't in the HTML 4 spec, so the HTML 5 spec is the current reference).

TLDR version of the spec: Spaces, angle brackets, ampersands, equals signs and double quotes are the only chars that get escaped when innerHTML is called.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably replacing them with HTML character entities, as per the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple. Umlaute and other character, are left alone (ü is NOT converted to ü). I've clarified my question in this regard.