# retrieve original html entity (decial) value as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make iphone apps like ibeer, imilk, ibug, ibeer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885152/how-to-make-iphone-apps-like-ibeer-imilk-ibug-ibeer)
>   [Use javascript to get raw html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905219/use-javascript-to-get-raw-html-code)

Let's say i have an html section like this:

```
<div id="post_content">
  <span>&#9654;<span>
</div>
```

(this is right pointing triangle)

I want to get the child of the "post_content" as raw html, that is as a string that is exactly the same as in the code above, so:

```
"<span>&#9654;<span>"
```

When I do

```
$('#post_content').html()
```

the content of the span get's transformed to something else it seems, when I post it using $.post() for example it turns into %E2%96%B6.

How do I get the content of post_content as a string that is exactly the same the original?

Comment: related: [rules regarding special characters/entities and innerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/712081/1048572)

Comment: check this answer
[You cannot get the actual HTML source of part of your web page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905503/885152

Comment: the above comment is corrent, i.e. it is not easily possible - second flying, if you post this your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here :

[How to decode HTML entities using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147359/how-to-decode-html-entities-using-jquery)

Basically using :

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(encodedStr).text();
```

Will get you what you want.

Comment: The OP wants to do it rather the other way round

Comment: That's not what I understand : When he posts the text as a variable, the post mecanism converts the entity again. So my answer provides a way to get back to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as explained in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3905503/885152) the received HTML is parsed into a DOM, only which is available to scripting. You only could get the plain text from the `responseText` of an XMLHttpRequest.

If you get the `innerHTML` from the DOM (what `$el.html()` does), it is serialized. HTML5 [specifies how to do that](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/serializing-html-fragments.html), but legacy browsers are most often not compliant.

You issue with `$.post()` is that this method sends the text in a HTTP request - encoded of course. What you see is just `encodeURIComponent` applied on the Unicode string you got. Try to `alert()` or `console.log()` the value, and you will see its true representation.